# Saving Access Report with Distinct Name

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-reports

I'm trying to save each individual employees statement using Access Reports. However I'm having issues with getting the `Employee Name` field to append to the `MyFileName` variable.

I'm able to export the individual employee reports as a PDF with the following format:

```
Statement_[EENo].pdf
```

However, I would like to have this to include the employee name in the following format:

```
Statement_[Employee Name]_[EENo].pdf
```

```
Private Sub Command2_Click()
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim MyFileName As String
    Dim mypath As String
    Dim temp As String

    mypath = "FILE LOCATION"

    Set db = CurrentDb()

    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT distinct [EENo] & [Employee Name] FROM [Query]", dbOpenSnapshot)

    rs.MoveFirst
    Do While Not rs.EOF
        temp = rs("EENo" & "Employee Name")
        MyFileName = "Statement" & "_" & [Employee Name] & "_" & Format(rs("EENo"), "000000") & ".PDF"

        DoCmd.OpenQuery "1 - Query: Firm Admin_EE"
        DoCmd.Close acQuery, "1 - Query: Firm Admin_EE", acSaveYes
        DoCmd.OpenReport "REPORT", acViewReport, , "[EENo]=" & temp
        DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "", acFormatPDF, mypath & MyFileName
        DoCmd.Close acReport, "REPORT"
        DoEvents

        rs.MoveNext
    Loop

    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
temp = rs("EENo").Value & rs("Employee Name").Value
MyFileName = "Statement_" & rs("Employee Name").Value & "_" & _
              Format(rs("EENo").Value, "000000") & ".PDF"
```

EDIT: I had not really looked at your SQL, and missed that you're combining the two columns in your query.  I don't use access but try:

```
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT distinct [EENo] , [Employee Name] FROM [Query]", _
                           dbOpenSnapshot)
```

Comment: Thanks Tim, I'll give that a try

Comment: I"ve added the code and get the following error: Run-time error '3265' Item not found in this collection. When I open the code this is whats getting the error: temp = rs("EENo" & "Employee Name")

Comment: I've tried the above update (temp = rs("EENo").Value & rs("Employee Name").Value) and get the error "Item not found in this collection". It must be something that i'm missing...

Comment: Edited again after actually looking at your SQL  You're only returning a single column in your query results.